# How to optimize the speed of site loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I must optimize speed of my [site](https://theappsdepot.com) loading, [this page](https://theappsdepot.com/games/strategy/clash-of-clans) in particular. As you see, page is large and have a lot of js- and img-files. Now time of site loading varies from 3,5 to 13 seconds (different services show different results). Help me with this question, please.

At this moment all included js- and css-files are complied into one file when page is loading. Also I'm planing to do lazy load to all pictures on page.

Comment: There are many aspects of optimizing loads times. It is more complex than can be covered here. Feel free to start a private chat with me if you'd like some help.

Comment: @AJ Funk, How to start a private chat here?

Comment: what if you minify your css and js files .. you can test your site here https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.gtmetrix.com and follow its suggestions. There are a lot of things you can do.

The online tool analyzes your website using various tools and provides useful insight on what actions you can take to reduce page load, like for example compress uncompressed images, defer Javascript code, etc.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Your edit seems to be limited to adding a bigger advertisement for the external site.

Comment: What would you suggest that I do? The online tool will obviously help the op.

Comment: Well, hope this one is better :/ Don't mind the downvote though